# scala for comprehension condition operation

Tags: scala, playframework, future

In my scala program, I have few operation in for-comprehension. I want to have a if condition inside like this,

```
user <- userDao.findUser(authToken)
haveDevice <- userDao.haveDevice(deviceId, deviceType)
if (haveDevice) {
   r <- userDao.addDevice(user.id, deviceId, deviceType)
}
```

But above code is invalid, how to do this? Thanks

Comment: What error it commits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

proper syntax for using if condition inside a for comprehension is as shown below.

```
for {
  user <- userDao.findUser(authToken)
  haveDevice <- userDao.haveDevice(deviceId, deviceType)
  r <- userDao.addDevice(user.id, deviceId, deviceType) if haveDevice
}
```

assuming your for comprehension operates on a Future, if the if condition fails then the entire comprehension returns a failed Future with error

> java.util.NoSuchElementException: Future.filter predicate is not
>   satisfied

Comment: What if user <- userOpt, userOpt is none, will it return NoSuchElementException?

Comment: if your for comprehension operate over an Option instead of Future then for None conditions you will not get NoSuchElementException exceptions. instead the output of the for comprehension will be None..